# C# Open file of text documents

Tags: c#, arrays, text

I'm quite new to C# and i'm trying to write a program that opens a folder from my computer containing multiple text documents. What I want to do is create an array of strings that stores the names of each of these text files in it. What I need is for someone to show me a way to get all those text file names stored into this array. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By "containing multiple text documents" you actually mean "containing multiple path/file names of text documents", right? Or is it an archive?

Comment: More information is needed. Is this file you're opening a text file that will contain the *names* of the other files you want to know about, or is this file an archive-type file (ZIP/TAR/RAR/CAB) which will actually contain the *data* of multiple files inside it?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a folder that contains multiple text files?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know where to begin. Do you have any experience with other frameworks? Do you understand something about I/O? How much do you know OO?

Comment: @Gage: Yes, I have a folder that contains multiple text files

Comment: If you need to read a file that contains multiple paths to files, u can use System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (pathToFile) that returns an array with all lines of the file. But your question is very incomplete, please put more information.

Comment: @Andre Calil: Yes, I do have experience with other frameworks, and I understand I/O and object oriented programming concepts. I am just unsure about how I got about getting all the .txt document's name from a certain folder and storing their names within an array.

Comment: A quick google search can yeild a lot of information including [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304430) article. Please reword your question using the [How to ask FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As is, this is not a question to be asked at SO.

Comment: OK. There is a conceptual difference between a "file" and a "folder". You stated you had a "file" that contained other "files"; by clarifying that your "file" is in fact a "folder" you've just made it all crystal-clear.

Comment: my apologies on the obscurity on the question I had.

Comment: You should edit your post so it makes sense - "opens a file from my computer containing" is very confusing and looking at your other comments is completely wrong. Also even with that your question should be answered with basic search - there are plenty how-to articles on MSDN - [How to: Get Information About Files, Folders, and Drives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6yk7a1b0.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment, use the code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace SQLiteEntityMigrator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string pathToDirectory = @"C:\Files";
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo diDir = new DirectoryInfo(pathToDirectory);
            System.IO.FileInfo[] files = diDir.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo lfileInfo in files)
            {
                // Work with files
                Console.WriteLine(lfileInfo.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to work with say the 4th file in this file array and make changes to it, how would I access this? I've tried a couple of things regarding your code and I have yet to find a solution.

Comment: ok, ´System.IO.FileInfo[] files´ is an array to access the fourth element of this array, just use ´files[3]´. What work do you want to accomplish with the file? the ´FileInfo´ class provides countless resources, see its documentation in Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx

Comment: I use the FileInfo class in an article on my blog to copy files and directories, check it out at: http://julioborges.p.ht/?p=710

Answer (score 2):

If all the text files are in the same directory, then this should help

```
        DirectoryInfo DR = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:/Path_to_file");
        FileInfo[] textFiles = DR.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

**EDIT :** 
To get the name of the files, you can use

```
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (FileInfo file in textFiles)
        {
            fileNames.Add(file.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Minor edits; this is the correct answer (one of them anyway).

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is create an array of strings that stores the names
>   of each of these text files in it

```
 List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
 fileNames.Add(yourFileName);
```

if you want to get all files from directory

```
 List<string> fileNames=  Directory.GetFiles("directorypath","*.txt").ToList();
```

Comment: The OP stated that he has the name of one file, in which there is information about other files. He wants the names of those files contained in the one file he does know. At best, this is an incomplete answer, at worst it's misleading and flat wrong.

Comment: @KeithS This is purely your assumption. I have answered based on what he has mentioned in the question. If OP updates his question and provides some more clear details, i will definitely update my answer.

Comment: @KeithS I have a folder that contains multiple text files, it means my answer is correct.

Comment: @KeithS i am waiting for you to remove your downvote, since my answer was correct in the first place.

Comment: Your original answer was little more than a snide comment and it wasn't until you revised it that it was even close. While others were trying to get the OP to clarify his question in the comments so they could give a helpful answer, your answer is the equivalent of a "First!" forum post. Your answer is still incomplete, it's still wrong based on the quote you incorporated stating he wants an *array*, and I will not remove my downvote because your behavior in posting this answer is reprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into `File.ReadAllLines`? You can grab a list of text files (listed line by line) in a file.

```
string[] fileNames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test\filePaths.txt");
foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fileName);
}
```

Comment: Given what the OP originally asked for, this was a good guess, but the OP has since clarified that the "file" he has is actually a "folder" aka a "directory".